# Using "and" with numbers

Tags: british-english, conjunctions, numbers

I'm a computer programmer and I'm working about [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=17) problem. I must say that I'm not very familiar with British English and I'd like to know when the word *and* is used in the numbers. The perfect answer for me will be something like *"The word and is used with numbers not divisible by 10"* (something mathematical). But all answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as [general ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals), but to answer your question:  British usage is to use "and" with numbers > 100 which are not divisible by 10.  For instance:  "Two hundred and thirty-five" but not "Three hundred".  American usage does not use the "and" at all.

Comment: Make that 'not divisible by 100', Lynn. "Two hundred and thirty"

Answer (score 4):

For British English, numbers greater than 100 and less than 1000 always include *and* between the “hundreds” figure and the other part:

> Three hundred and forty-two
>   Four hundred

Numbers greater than 1000 include *and* between **any** “hundreds” figure and the figure less than 100, and then state the multiple:

> Five thousand, three hundred
>   Three hundred and forty-two thousand, two hundred and fifty-one
>   One million, three hundred thousand, four hundred and twenty
>   Two thousand, three hundred and sixty-two million

That is, any of the three-figure groups in a large number follow the first rule before stating the multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Find out the result. All numbers numbers above 100 that are not divisible by 100 includes the word *and*.

Comment: Numbers above 100 and not divisible by 10 include 'and'? So you'd say 'Two hundred fifty'? Interesting, as this is certainly not the case with spoken Australian (and I would've thought British) English. We'd say 'Two hundred **and** fifty'.

Comment: Snubian, British people also say 'Two hundred **and** fifty'.

Comment: Note that the answer has been edited, rendering Snubian's comment irrelevant.